# KeyValuePair in WCF Service

Tags: c#, wcf, serialization

I have a WCF service, with a method UpdateProperty that take a PropertyValue in parameter :

```
void UpdateProperty(PropertyValue propertyValue)

[DataContract]
public class PropertyValue
{
    [DataMember]
    public string Property { get; private set; }

    [DataMember]
    public object Value { get; private set; }
}
```

I'm trying to call the method with a KeyValuePair as Value, and I'm getting this error :

> "The formatter threw an exception while trying to deserialize the
>   message: There was an error while trying to deserialize parameter
>   http://tempuri.org/:propertyValue. The InnerException message was
>   'Error in line 1 position 544. Element
>   'http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/MyProject.DataContracts:Value'
>   contains data from a type that maps to the name
>   'http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System.Collections.Generic:KeyValuePairOfanyTypeanyType'.
>   The deserializer has no knowledge of any type that maps to this name.
>   Consider using a DataContractResolver if you are using
>   DataContractSerializer or add the type corresponding to
>   'KeyValuePairOfanyTypeanyType' to the list of known types - for
>   example, by using the KnownTypeAttribute attribute or by adding it to
>   the list of known types passed to the serializer.'.  Please see
>   InnerException for more details."

I tried to add a KnownType on my class but I still get the error :

```
[KnownType(typeof(KeyValuePair<object, object>))]
```

Any idea why ? I'm using other KeyValuePair in other method (as parameter) without problem...

In my SOAP body, I have :

```
    <d4p1:Value xmlns:d7p1="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System.Collections.Generic" i:type="d7p1:KeyValuePairOfanyTypeanyType">
      <d7p1:key>test</d7p1:key>
      <d7p1:value>test</d7p1:value>
    </d4p1:Value>
```

Comment: What is the actual type of `KeyValuePair<,>` that you are serializing over the wire?  Is it really a `KeyValuePair<object, object>` or is it, say, a `KeyValuePair<string, string>`?

Comment: I tried both, but what I really need for my use case is a KeyValuePair<DateTime, DateTime>

Comment: It seems that he didn't know the Type that you use in your Property `Value`. Mark your class `PropertyValue` with `[KnownType( typeof(MyType) )]`, `MyType` is the Type that you give him in the `Value` Property.

Comment: 1) Can you show how you put the `[KnownType(typeof(KeyValuePair<object, object>))]` attribute on `PropertyValue`?  Did you modify the contract on both the client and server sides to include this known type?

Comment: I simply added it to the class on the server. Then I updated the service reference on the client. In the generated proxy, I have the new KnownType but it still doesn't work :

    [System.Runtime.Serialization.KnownTypeAttribute(typeof(System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair<object, object>))]
    public partial class PropertyValue : object, System.Runtime.Serialization.IExtensibleDataObject, System.ComponentModel.INotifyPropertyChanged {

Comment: I didn't find the solution for the KeyValuePair but as workaround, I created a new class instead, that I convert to KeyValuePair in my method...

Comment: If I serialize manually with `DataContractSerializer`, I see there should be [`i:type`](https://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-1/#xsi_type) attributes on the key and value elements as well, e.g.: `<d2p1:key xmlns:d3p1="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" i:type="d3p1:string">hello</d2p1:key>`  (Full XML [here](http://pastebin.com/LJgEWBDr).)  The lack of explicit type attributes is likely causing the problem in deserialization.  But I don't know why they are not present.

Answer (score 0):

i guess i know what you want. try this object as your input:

```
    [Serializable]
public class WebServiceInputGetDataParams : ISerializable
{
    public Dictionary<string, object> Entries
    {
        get { return entries; }
    }


    private Dictionary<string, object> entries;
    public WebServiceInputGetDataParams()
    {
        entries = new Dictionary<string, object>();
    }
    protected WebServiceInputGetDataParams(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
    {
        entries = new Dictionary<string, object>();
        foreach (var entry in info)
        {
            entries.Add(entry.Name, entry.Value);
        }
    }
    public void GetObjectData(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
    {
        foreach (var entry in entries)
        {
            info.AddValue(entry.Key, entry.Value);
        }
    }
}
```